# array difference returning edited values

Tags: php

The following code checks the first array(parameter1) aginst the second array(parameter2) and returns an array that tells which elements were modified.

```
$array_data   = array(
    "studDetails" => array(
        "studDet" => array(
            "studClass" => "V",
        ),
    ),
    "email"       => "kavya@opspl.com",
    "systemNames" => array("EMR"),
);
$array_edited = $array_data;

//EDITING
$array_edited['email'] = "kam";
$array_edited['studDetails']['studDet']['studClass'] = "VV";

echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_diff_assoc2_deep($array_edited, $array_data));


function array_diff_assoc2_deep($array_edited, $array_data)
{
    $difference = array();
    foreach ($array_edited as $row => $value) {
        if (!isset($array_data[$row]) && !empty($value)) {
            $difference['added'][$row] = $value;
        } else if (is_array($array_edited[$row]) && is_array($array_data[$row])) {
            $difference[$row] = array_diff_assoc2_deep($array_edited[$row], $array_data[$row]);
        } else if ((string)$value != (string)$array_data[$row]) {
            $difference['edited'][$row] = array("old" => $array_data[$row], "new" => $value);
        }

    }
    $difference = array_filter($difference);
    return $difference;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array (
    [studDetails] => Array (
        [studDet] => Array (
            [edited] => Array (
                [studClass] => Array (
                    [old] => V 
                    [new] => VV 
                )
            )
        )
    )
    [edited] => Array (
        [email] => Array (
            [old] => kavya@opspl.com 
            [new] => kam 
        )
    )
)
```

I want the output to be in a single edited key no matter how many internal arrays are there.

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
Array (
    [edited] => Array (
        [email] => Array (
            [old] => kavya@opspl.com 
            [new] => kam 
        )
        [studClass] => Array (
            [old] => V 
            [new] => VV 
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is the recursive call:

```
$difference[$row] = array_diff_assoc2_deep($array_edited[$row], $array_data[$row]);
```

With this line, you put each recursive comparison result into a separate key.

If you don't do this but keep the resulting array flat, you'll get what you want:

```
function array_diff_assoc2_deep($array_edited, $array_data, $difference = array())
{
    foreach ($array_edited as $row => $value) {
        if (!isset($array_data[$row]) && !empty($value)) {
            $difference['added'][$row] = $value;
        } else if (is_array($array_edited[$row]) && is_array($array_data[$row])) {
            $difference = array_diff_assoc2_deep($array_edited[$row], $array_data[$row], $difference);
        } else if ((string)$value != (string)$array_data[$row]) {
            $difference['edited'][$row] = array("old" => $array_data[$row], "new" => $value);
        }

    }
    $difference = array_filter($difference);
    return $difference;
}
```

Three lines have changed:

```
function array_diff_assoc2_deep($array_edited, $array_data, $difference = array())
//{
## REMOVED: $difference = array();
//  foreach ($array_edited as $row => $value) {
//      if (!isset($array_data[$row]) && !empty($value)) {
//          $difference['added'][$row] = $value;
//      } else if (is_array($array_edited[$row]) && is_array($array_data[$row])) {
            $difference = array_diff_assoc2_deep($array_edited[$row], $array_data[$row], $difference);
//      } else if ((string)$value != (string)$array_data[$row]) {
//          $difference['edited'][$row] = array("old" => $array_data[$row], "new" => $value);
//      }
//
//  }
//  $difference = array_filter($difference);
//  return $difference;
//}
```

You can see the output [here](https://eval.in/803731).